# Show highest score from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in `this.state`. Array has objects having 2 keys: [text] and [score].

I need to display [text] key only of object with highest score. 
e.g.

> [{
>   text: 'foo',
>   score: 1,
>   },
>   {
>   text: 'bar',
>   score: 0.1,
>   }]

Here highest score is 1 with [text] key value as "foo".
So just render "foo".

Code:

```js
class Score extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = 
       {
       text: [
         {
         title: 'el', 
         data: [
           {
             el: 'hello',
             score: 1
           },
           {
             el:  'hallo',
             score: 0.10
           }
         ]
         },
       ] 
       
       }
  }
  
 
            
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
          this.state.text.map((q, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="card">
             
                {
                  q.data.map((i, j) => 
                    (
                    <div key={j}>
                     <p>{i.el}</p>
                     <p>{i.score}</p>
                    
                      </div>
                    )
                 )}
             
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Score />, Root);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#map` will display every element, not just that one with highest score.

Inside map you should drop some logic which will find the object with highest score and display it.

```
this.state.text.map((q, i) => {
   const r = q.data.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)[0];
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ sort ascending and pick the first element

   return (
      <div key={i} className="card">
         <p>{r.el}</p>
         <p>{r.score}</p>
      </div>
   );
})
```

```js
const r = [{ text: 'hello', score: 1 }, { text: 'hallo', score: 0.1 }];
const res = r.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)[0];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please note that this implementation is not very recommended performance-wise, because the sorting will be done on every render.

Comment: @yagiro As long as the `text` array doesn't have millions of entries, there will be no performance issues :) Anyways the loop (sort/reduce/find) has to occur. BTW - I agree with you, the 'highest' score element found logic should be placed e.g. when the `text` is fetched so it happens only once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce and find the highest before rendering.

```
const maxObject = this.state.text.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.score > current.score) ? prev : current
},this.state.text[0])
```

and then you can use this maxObject in your jsx.

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort the values, but your structure is such that you need to search inside the first object of your `text` array...

relevant **js**:

```
import React from "react";

class Score extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const dataForArray = [
      {
        title: "el",
        data: [
          {
            el: "hello",
            score: 1
          },
          {
            el: "hallo",
            score: 1.1
          },
          {
            el: "hallo",
            score: 0.1
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    let dataToSort = dataForArray[0].data;
    if (dataToSort) {
      const highestVal = dataToSort.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score )[0];
      console.log("highest:", highestVal);
    }
    this.state = { text: dataForArray, highest:highestVal };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.text.map((q, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="card">
            {q.data.map((i, j) => (
              <div key={j}>
                <p>{i.el}</p>
                <p>{i.score}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
        <hr/>
        Highest value is: <b> {this.state.highest.el} - {this.state.highest.score} </b>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Score;
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dazuzy)